# Associate Azure Sql tables with Offline Easy Tables

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, offlineapps

we are trying to **associate Already defined SQL tables** with Easy Tables on Azure.
Unfortunately,if we associate existing tables with Easy tables **Data is Not being Synced** in local store.

> Can any one could suggest me whats wrong!
>
> Is Easy  table (Offline sync) supports existing schema .?

What considerations to follow to have match the Existing Schema with Easy tables ? viz An Id should be a string.

Answer (score 0):

The easy table is used in the Node.js backend. If you create a Node.js backend, Azure will auto create the Node.js backend without deploy. It will auto bind the Azure SQL database table (or Azure storage account) into the easy table.

But if you use C# backend, Azure will not bind the table to the easy table. Because the C# backend use EF codefirst to create a table. If the request sends to the backend, EF will auto create the table.

You may refer this [blog](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-handling-conflicts-offline-data.md), which describes regarding “Handling conflicts with offline data sync in Mobile Apps” and see if it helps.

Comment: Its a great reference, but is there any way we can use Easy tables with C# Back-end? Eventually if i create a table through Portal its working fine but the vice-versa is not happening

Comment: How do we Re-Use the Tables in SQL Azure or How can we Enable Offline for existing DB Tables.?

Comment: We have implemented this convention too..   https://stackoverflow.com/a/33047786/4768363